# Webpage loads in simulator's safari mac safari but does not load in webView iOS obj C

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview, safari

The URL Being:-

```
http://1-dot-smartrefill-968.appspot.com/#/#mfucci@gmail_com
```

ATS is disabled

My code is as follows:-

```
-(void)loadView
{
    [super loadView];
    self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    self.webview = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    [self.webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://1-dot-smartrefill-968.appspot.com/#/#mfucci@gmail_com"]]];
    [self.view addSubview:self.webview];
    self.webview.delegate=self;


}
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSLog(@"Finished loading");
}
-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Error %@", error);
}
```

The URL loading in Safari.

[image]

I tried many diffeernt solutions but none of them seem to work. Please help out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your NSURL will be always nil because of some un-encoded values in the URlString

```
[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://1-dot-smartrefill-968.appspot.com/#/#mfucci@gmail_com"]
```

The above line will always give you a nil value.

try this:

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://1-dot-smartrefill-968.appspot.com/#/#mfucci@gmail_com";

NSURl *Url = [NSURL URLWithString:[self.urlString stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]]];
```

try loading the url value that you get from the above conversion. Hope this helps.

Thanks!

Comment: Still not loading Error Log:- Error Error Domain=WebKitErrorDomain Code=102 "Frame load interrupted" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=file://http%3A%2F%2F1-dot-smartrefill-968.appspot.com%2F%23%2F%23mfucci%40gmail_com, NSLocalizedDescription=Frame load interrupted, NSErrorFailingURLKey=file://http%3A%2F%2F1-dot-smartrefill-968.appspot.com%2F%23%2F%23mfucci%40gmail_com}